# NodeMCU ESP8266 Returns IP address, but cant open the web with IP address

Tags: esp8266

I have used the below code with proper Wifi Address and password. The Nodemcu connects to WIfi, and displays IP address, But the IP address cannot be used to open a web page. It says "This site cant be reached". Can anyone help with this

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "***";
const char* password = "*******";

int ledPin = D0;
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {

  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Wifi connecting to ");
  Serial.println( ssid );

  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting");

  while( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ){
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");        
  }


  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("Wifi Connected Success!");
  Serial.print("NodeMCU IP Address : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP() );

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("NodeMCU Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");

}

void loop() {

    // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("Hello New client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

   // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

   // Match the request

  int value = LOW;
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    value = HIGH;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1)  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    value = LOW;
  }

// Set ledPin according to the request
//digitalWrite(ledPin, value);

  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Led pin is now: ");

  if(value == HIGH) {
    client.print("On");
  } else {
    client.print("Off");
  }
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=ON\"\"><button>Turn On </button></a>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/LED=OFF\"\"><button>Turn Off </button></a><br />");  
  client.println("</html>");

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
  Serial.println("");

}
```

Comment: you must read the request. flush() doesn't do it. browsers don't like a response before they finished to send a request. see the WiFiWebServer example in the IDE examples menu

Comment: the example is now renamed to WiFiManualWebServer

Comment: Are you sure you are on the same wifi network as the esp unit ? eg. don't do it from your cellular connected phone.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution to this problem?